# Is this text wrong about output impedance variation

Tags: bjt

Regarding the following section from a book:

[image]

It says:

> As the base current increases the slope of the line increases,
> resulting in an increase in output impedance with increase in base and
> collector current.

So it says increase in base current results in an increase in output impedance.

But isn't the output impedance decreasing with increasing base current?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. The book has an error.

Comment: Just use the formula 5.2. If numerator=constant ... If Icq gets greater, ro decrease ...

Comment: Perhaps, as it is in the case of the study of Early effect, it would say (?) that if VEarly gets higher, ro get higher (?) ...

Comment: Maybe it only increases in early 1952.

Comment: Earlier in the paragraph, the authors do get it right *The steeoer the slope, the less the output impedance and the less ideal the transistor.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It seems the author confused himself.

The higher the slope, the *smaller* the output impedance. So it should read *... resulting in a **decrease** in output impedance*.

Is this the Sarma book, btw? I had bad experiences with it as an undergrad.

Comment: It was Boylestad's book. He was born in 1939 so I doubt he checks his emails.

Answer (score 0):

The output impedance is inversely proportional to the slope of the I vs V curve since impedance is expressed as V/I. Looking at the curve, you can see that the slope is approaching 0 as the current is increased. This means that, for a given change in voltage, the change in current is less. This, in turn, means that the impedance has increased. This is to be expected since in the basic model of a transistor, the collector acts as a current source. An ideal current source has infinite impedance. A real transistor can only approach this but it does get better as the current increases which is what the curve shows.

Comment: Your final sentence should read "as the current decreases" and not *as the current increases* (I reckon).

Comment: @barry slope of the curve(dI/dV) is not the output impedance, but its inverse is.

Comment: Indeed the curve goes more horizontal with increasing emitter current, but that is not the question. The question assk about increasing base current. Each line in the characteristic represents a fixed base current.